# Content Types for a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

***Overview:***
I built a SharePoint Document Library that has a Word template that the end users come in and fill out when selecting "new". I have a content types allowed on the document library.

***Question:***
Do you need to create a new content type for different type of document such as Word, PowerPoint, and Excel or can the content type be used for all documents when loading to the library and filling out the fields?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each document template, you need to create a separate content type.
Here is an official guidance for your reference:
[Associate a document template with a content type](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsharepoint%2Fcreate-customize-content-type%23associate-a-document-template-with-a-content-type&data=05%7C01%7Cv-jingsun2%40microsoft.com%7Ca4203ebe73044b0ea19c08da8b1eca3e%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637975261682046287%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=m61DY47TFrQLpxoqnYqloJruoi6FnKv4Xce%2BJnsUzMA%3D&reserved=0)

Comment: Is there any new progress , and if you have extra questions about my answer, please click "Comment".